# combine ggplots from dataframes with different lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram, density-plot

I have two ggplots from data frames of different lengths for which I have plotted the histogram of one column separately like below. I want to combine these two plots into one ggplot with two different y axes, one on the right and one on the left for the two data frames. How can I do this?

```
a = ggplot(GG, aes(x = as.numeric(Kstat))) +
  theme_pubclean()

a + geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(Kstat)), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 0.6) + xlim(0,1000)+ylim(0,0.1)

b = ggplot(all, aes(x = as.numeric(Kstat))) +
  theme_pubclean()

b + geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(Kstat)), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 0.6) + xlim(0,1000)+ylim(0,0.5)
```

Comment: Don't have the time to work on an example. check out https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html.
Note, while it is doable, think about whether placing 2 graphs next to each other convey your message in a better way.

Comment: Put your data into long format then facet the plots you want to compare. If you could add some sample data for your two dataframes that would help test and verify a solution. Paste your data into the question using `dput(your_dataframe)` [MRE] gives some hints about asking a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your data, so here's an example with a dataset included in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- diamonds[1:10,7]
df2 <- diamonds[100:2100,7]
```

For this example, the data in df1 is much less varied and so the density spike is ~25x higher.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = df1, aes(x = price)) +
  geom_vline(data = df1, aes(xintercept = mean(price)), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 0.6) +
  geom_density(data = df2, aes(x = price), color = "red") +
  geom_vline(data = df2, aes(xintercept = mean(price)), 
             linetype = "dashed", color = "red", size = 0.6)
```

[image]

One way to deal with this would be to scale the df2 density up 25x and to create a secondary axis with the inverse adjustment. (This is how secondary axes work in ggplot2; you first scale the data into the primary axis, and then create a secondary axis as an annotation that helps the reader interpret it.)

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = df1, aes(x = price)) +
  geom_vline(data = df1, aes(xintercept = mean(price)), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 0.6) +
  geom_density(data = df2, aes(x = price, y = ..density.. * 25), color = "red") +
  geom_vline(data = df2, aes(xintercept = mean(price)), 
             linetype = "dashed", color = "red", size = 0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ~ . / 25) +
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: "I just want to know how much of my data falls in a range of numbers like a histogram." This is a vague question and will be hard to answer without more explanation. Also, I can't make any sense from your list of summary stats -- what should we be seeing from that?

Comment: Sorry. Please ignore what I just said. I was misunderstood.